# How can I change the color of the selected point in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an HighCharts line plot in which the user can click points using this code:

```
 plotOptions: {
     series: {
        point: {
           events: {
              click: function(event) {
               // some processing
              }
 ...
```

I want to change the color of the selected point.

I know that I could write :

```
marker: {
   states: {
      select: {
         fillColor: 'red',
...
```

But, in my case, I really need to do this inside `click`, How can I do it ?

Comment: It may be a good idea to also elaborate on why you want to explicitly handle it on the click event yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the `update` function for that:

```
    plotOptions:{
        series:{
            marker:{
                states:{
                    select:{
                        lineColor:'red',
                        fillColor:'red'
                    }
                }
            },
            point:
            {
              events:{
                  click: function(){
                      this.setState("select");
                      this.update({
                          marker:{
                              fillColor:'red',
                              lineColor:'red',
                          }
                      })
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    },
```

When `this` refers to the point the user clicked.
As you can see, I composed a custom "select" state with some custom properties, and applied this state when user clicks a point. I also used `update` in order to change the point marker attributes, so I make sure the point reserves the new attributes after the state is no longer active:

http://jsfiddle.net/gprevqdf/2/

Comment: The combination `setState()` and `update()` is very interesting indeed. I have a question however: playing with your fiddle, I can't see why `marker:{ states:{ select` is still needed. Can you shade some light on this ?

Comment: You could probably do away with the selected state if you are directly doing the `point.update`

Comment: Hey @M.Page, I used the state property since that in a "regular" chart, Highcharts will apply it's own `select` proprety (when a click event is fired). I added these lines in order to override these properties and apply my own...